# OpenLdap Docker Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ldap, openldap

I trying to add an entry to my OpenLdap server that is launched on a docker container.

After running the following command:

```
docker exec -it openldap ldapadd -x -w "adminpw" -D "cn=admin,dc=exemple,dc=com" -f ${PWD}/ldif/file.ldif
```

I get this error :

```
file.ldif: No such file or directory
```

Knowing that I use a valid path to my ldif file.

This is the contain of my docker-compose file

```
  openldap:
    image: osixia/openldap:latest
    container_name: openldap
    hostname: ldap-server
    ports: 
      - "390:390"
      - "636:636"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certificates:/container/service/slapd/assets/certs
      - ./data/slapd/database:/var/lib/ldap
      - ./data/slapd/config:/etc/ldap/slapd.d
    environment: 
      - LDAP_ORGANISATION=supplychain
      - LDAP_DOMAIN=supplychain.com
      - LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpw
      - LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD=config_pass
      - "LDAP_BASE_DN=dc=exemple,dc=com" #cn=admin,dc=exemple,dc=com  
      - LDAP_TLS_CRT_FILENAME=server.crt
      - LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILENAME=server.key
      - LDAP_TLS_CA_CRT_FILENAME=exemple.com.ca.crt
    networks: 
      - supplychain
  
  phpldapadmin:
    image: osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
    container_name: phpldapadmin
    hostname: phpldapadmin
    ports: 
      - "81:80"
    environment: 
      - PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=openldap
      - PHPLDAPADMIN_HTTPS=false
    depends_on:
      - openldap
    networks: 
      - supplychain
```

Comment: "Knowing that I use a valid path to my ldif file." you can trust the "no such file or directory"  message.    It might be that the path is not what you expect.  You're putting the file in the docker container?   Bear in mind that `${PWD}` is going to be executed by the shell running `docker exec`, not within the container.

Comment: I changed "${PWD}./tmp/file.ldif"  to  "/tmp/file.ldif".  it works now. thank you for your reply